# Calendar hour set to 0, yet displays 1, why?

Tags: java, datetime, calendar, timezone

I am running into a strange issue with Java Calendar.

The following code adds 3 hours consecutively from a date starting at midnight.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+0"));

    // Setting to January 29th, 1920 at 00:00:00
    // now.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+0"));
    now.set(Calendar.YEAR, 1920);
    now.set(Calendar.MONTH, 0);
    now.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 29);
    now.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
    now.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    now.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    now.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);       

    now.setLenient(false);

    int threeHours = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 3;

    SimpleDateFormat sdf
        = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss SSS");

    for (int i=0;i<25;i++) {

        System.out.println(sdf.format(now.getTime()));
        now.add(Calendar.MILLISECOND, threeHours);

    }

}
```

Yet, the displayed result is:

```
1920-01-29 01:00:00 000
1920-01-29 04:00:00 000
1920-01-29 07:00:00 000
1920-01-29 10:00:00 000
1920-01-29 13:00:00 000
1920-01-29 16:00:00 000
1920-01-29 19:00:00 000
1920-01-29 22:00:00 000
1920-01-30 01:00:00 000
1920-01-30 04:00:00 000
1920-01-30 07:00:00 000
1920-01-30 10:00:00 000
1920-01-30 13:00:00 000
1920-01-30 16:00:00 000
1920-01-30 19:00:00 000
1920-01-30 22:00:00 000
1920-01-31 01:00:00 000
1920-01-31 04:00:00 000
1920-01-31 07:00:00 000
1920-01-31 10:00:00 000
1920-01-31 13:00:00 000
1920-01-31 16:00:00 000
1920-01-31 19:00:00 000
1920-01-31 22:00:00 000
1920-02-01 01:00:00 000
```

Why is the first hour 1 and not 0? I am located at GMT+1, could this be related?

Comment: Have you considered using jodatime?

Comment: @BigMike I can't find any methods related daylight in Calendar...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `now.getTime()` gets the `Date` which doesn't have a time zone.

Try setting the timezone with

```
sdf.setTimeZone(now.getTimeZone());
```

Answer (score 2):

i guess you should use
now.set(Calendar.HOUR, 0); instead  now.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);

Comment: Wrong. `HOUR` means hour within AM or PM (apart from the general recommendation no linger to use `Calendar` after the advent of java.time, the modern Java date and time API).

Answer (score 1):

now it should work fine

```
        Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
        TimeZone timezone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+0");
        now.set(Calendar.YEAR, 1920);
        now.set(Calendar.MONTH, 0);
        now.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 29);
        now.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
        now.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        now.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        now.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);       
        now.setLenient(false);
        int threeHours = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 3;
        SimpleDateFormat sdf
            = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss SSS");
        sdf.setTimeZone(timezone);
        for (int i=0;i<25;i++) {
            System.out.println(sdf.format(now.getTime()));
            now.add(Calendar.MILLISECOND, threeHours);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

## *java.time*

The terrible `Calendar` class was supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310. Specifically replaced by [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html). There is no point to investing time and effort in understanding `Calendar` — [Sun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sun_Microsystems), [Oracle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_Corporation), and the [JCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Community_Process) community all gave up on that flawed class, and so should we.

Your purpose uses UTC rather than a particular time zone. So [`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html) is appropriate.

```
// Setting to January 29th, 1920 at 00:00:00 in UTC.
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 1920 , Month.JANUARY , 29 ) ;
LocalTime lt = LocalTime.MIN ;
ZoneOffset offset = ZoneOffset.UTC ;
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.of( ld , lt , offset ) ;
```

Add 3 hours at a time, 25 times. Use [`Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Duration.html) to represent a span-of-time on the scale of hours-minutes-seconds. Pass the `Duration` object to [`OffsetDatetime::plus`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html#plus(java.time.temporal.TemporalAmount)), as a [`TemporalAmount`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/temporal/TemporalAmount.html).

```
Duration d = Duration.ofHours( 3 ) ;
for( int i = 0 ; i < 25 ; i ++ )
{
    System.out.println( odt ) ; 
    // Set up the next loop.
    odt = odt.plus( d ) ;
}
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/ItigXX).

```
odt.toString(): 1920-01-29T00:00Z
1920-01-29T00:00Z
1920-01-29T03:00Z
1920-01-29T06:00Z
1920-01-29T09:00Z
1920-01-29T12:00Z
1920-01-29T15:00Z
1920-01-29T18:00Z
1920-01-29T21:00Z
1920-01-30T00:00Z
1920-01-30T03:00Z
1920-01-30T06:00Z
1920-01-30T09:00Z
1920-01-30T12:00Z
1920-01-30T15:00Z
1920-01-30T18:00Z
1920-01-30T21:00Z
1920-01-31T00:00Z
1920-01-31T03:00Z
1920-01-31T06:00Z
1920-01-31T09:00Z
1920-01-31T12:00Z
1920-01-31T15:00Z
1920-01-31T18:00Z
1920-01-31T21:00Z
1920-02-01T00:00Z
```

---

[image: Table of all date-time types in Java, both modern and legacy]

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes. Hibernate 5 & JPA 2.2 support *java.time*.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - [**Java 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) brought some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android (26+) bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), a process known as [*API desugaring*](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support#library-desugaring) brings a [subset of the *java.time*](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) functionality not originally built into Android.

    - If the desugaring does not offer what you need, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above) to Android. See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).